# Wordpress to show visitor's IP in the title

Tags: php, wordpress

My question: Is there any way of showing the visitor's IP address in the *title* of a page on Wordpress? What I've done so far is this: [My IP Lookup](http://nix-pix.co.uk/ip/).

Is there any plugin or a tweak that I can do to?

Here's the file: [Header.php](http://nix-pix.co.uk/header.txt)

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the theme and its framework. I'm just going to modify the code that Matthew gave you a bit. For future updates to the theme and framework, it's better if you can avoid actually editing header.php in your [Child theme](http://www.wpjumpstart.com/tutorial/child-theme-setup/), but instead utilize the framework's hook system:

http://www.wpjumpstart.com/tutorial/primary-framework-action-hooks/

themeblvd_title is one of the framework's actions. It has a default function already hooked onto it that displays the title the way you see it now. What you want to do is fairly easy because you're not actually modifying that default function, but instead just adding onto the action.

If the concept of action hooks in general is completely foreign to you, definitely check out this article -- **www.wpjumpstart.com/tutorial/actions/** -- Understanding these basic WordPress development concepts is really going to expand what you're going to be able to do moving forward with your customizations.

So to accomplish what Mathew said, you'd do the following from the functions.php of your Child theme:

```
function my_title_addon() {
    if (is_page(10)) { //Check if we are on the correct page
        echo '|'; //Just a spacer between the default title and your addition
        do_shortcode('[shortcode]');
    }
}
add_action( 'themeblvd_title', 'my_title_addon' );
```

There's also one big thing to note here, as well. I noticed on your site, you're using Alyeska 2.0. You should update to the latest version Alyeska 2.1 posted last week on ThemeForest, which incorporates v2.1 of the framework. Inside is a new sample child theme that incorporates a slightly modified structure, as outlined in this video -- **vimeo.com/41331677**

If you do not use this new child theme structure, the above code I posted will add your IP shortcode to the *start* of themeblvd_title, which isn't what you want. If you elect to keep your current theme version and Child theme structure, the above `add_action` needs to have a priority higher than the default 10 like this:

```
function my_title_addon() {
    if (is_page(10)) { //Check if we are on the correct page
        echo '|'; //Just a spacer between the default title and your addition
        do_shortcode('[shortcode]');
    }
}
add_action( 'themeblvd_title', 'my_title_addon', 11 ); // Higher priority so it comes after default title function
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `header.php` file in your theme. That is where the  tag is generated. It should be wp-content/themes/alyeska-child/header.php or if it isn't there wp-content/themes/alyeska/header.php.

If you post the code that is generating your title (or your `header.php` file if you can't tell), we can tell you where to add it specifically.

If the IP info is generated via a shortcode, you can use `do_shortcode('[shortcode])` in your PHP to run the shortcode directly with PHP.

If you wanted to do this on just one page, you would have to detect the correct page and conditionalize the change to the title. You need to know a page identifyer for the page you want, but you would use something like:

```
<title>
<?php
    themeblvd_title();
    if (is_page(10)) { //Check if we are on the correct page
        echo '|'; //Just a spacer between the default title and your addtion
        do_shortcode('[shortcode]');
    }
?>
</title>
```

More information on is_page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Comment: the thing is, I'm using a plugin with a shortcode to generate the user's details, and I'm not sure shortcodes work in php!! :D

Comment: Added shortcode details. You can use `do_shortcode('[shortcode])`

Comment: By the way, how can I use this only on _one_ page and not all of them?

Comment: Where exactly do i use this? here's a link to my header.php: http://nix-pix.co.uk/header.txt

Comment: It looks like your theme is using it's own function to generate the titles. `<title><?php themeblvd_title(); ?></title>`. You can use the is_page() to work around that. I'll update my example.

Comment: by the way, how can I include: <?php if (function_exists('js_aboutvisitor_display')) {
  js_aboutvisitor_display(array(os=>0;browser=>0));
} ?> in the title?

Comment: You can include whatever you would like in the title. That is a JS function specific to your plugin so I'm not sure what it does. All shortcodes should work with the 'do_shortcode' WordPress function.

Comment: HURRAY!!!!! It worked!! _Now_ I get it! It didn't work, because I forgot to add `echo` before the `do_shortcode`!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use a filter hook to modify the title.

Add this in a theme functions.php file or one of your own plugins:

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'add_ip_to_title', 10, 3 );

function add_ip_to_title($title, $sep = '', $location = '') {
    return $title . $sep . "visitor IP info here";
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title

Comment: this is the best way to do this. It it the closest way to keeping seperation of DOM and server side code.

Comment: Just as a side note, this would only work if the wp_title was being used in header.php to generate the title (it probably is).

Comment: what do I put in the "visitor ip info here"? because the shortcode doesn't work!

Comment: This may not work because your theme is using a custom function to generate the title.

Comment: @NickSelensky If you look in the source code of the IP plugin, you may find some functions that the shortcodes call that get the info.  If you only want to show the IP, just use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Answer (score 0):

To add to some of the other answers, to get their IP address, it could vary a little bit depending upon your server environment.  Just make a file called test.php and put it in a web accessible place:

```
<?php

echo phpinfo();

?>
```

Then, look for a place where you can retrieve the user's IP address.  If your PHP is running in a reverse proxy, unfortunately, the normal place will just have localhost's IP.  But there are a lot of other environmental variables you can grab the IP from.  Here are the places to check:

"Apache Environment" or "HTTP Headers Information" or under the "PHP Variables" section.

Then, if you see the real IP address (compare the address shown on the info page with what you might get from whatismyip.com) then you can access that value in the function described above by drew010 using one of PHP's [predefined variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php).